# batch identify files filled with zeros

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

I have some folders which contain files (old temp P2P files saved wrongly apparently) which are just filled with zeros - any program/batch that can verify this ? I do not want to open each one with a hex editor

Comment: What kind of files ?

Comment: 023.part - bunch of zeros - there are too many to check all of them individually

Comment: About what size are the files?

Comment: Anything from a few megs to a few gigs

Comment: Look if anyone knew how to write a C++ snippet or a batch that checks CRC - CRC must be 00000000 if and only if file is zeros - right ?

Comment: Not necessarily. You're right that a lot of popular CRC algorithms will evaluate to zero if a file is all zeroes or empty. However, for these same algorithms, appending the CRC of any given file to that file will cause the CRC of the new file to evaluate to zero.For example,

Comment: (Oops, continued from above.) For example, using the standard CRC-16 algorithm, a file containing the hex byte 01 will have a little-endian CRC of C0C1; appending the hex bytes C1 C0 to the file will cause it to have a CRC of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Though it runs the risk of false positives (like most CRC-based solutions), if PowerShell and a Java runtime environment are installed, it is possible to do approximately what you're asking for after downloading and extracting [Jacksum](http://www.jonelo.de/java/jacksum/index.html).

Adapt the following command (the `$jacksum_root_directory` variable should have no trailing slash), then open PowerShell and run it to get a listing of files with a checksum of zero:

```
$jacksum_root_directory = 'drive:\path\to\directory'
$jacksum_jar_location = 'drive:\path\to\jacksum.jar'
java -jar $jacksum_jar_location -E dec -F "#CHECKSUM #FILENAME" -a crc64 -p -r -f $jacksum_root_directory | where { $_.StartsWith('0 ') } | foreach { get-item $_.Remove(0, 2) }
```

All zeroed-out and empty files will have a checksum of zero and should show in the listing, but it's possible that other, non-zeroed files may also have a zero checksum.

When you feel confident that the files listed can be safely deleted, they can be deleted automatically by replacing `get-item` with `remove-item` in the third line and re-running the command.